# Ondrop function. Help me complete my function.

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to make a feature of my website where there are multiple pictures and you have to drag an icon ( Turtle ) into a box. I managed to find some codes for what happen if you drag the correct icon.

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    window.location.assign("homepage.html");
}

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="turtle.ico" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" 
width="100" height="100">
<img draggable="true" width="100" height="100" src="fish.ico">
```

I am now having trouble of writing the code for what happen if you drag the wrong icon (fish.ico) . I am planning for it to have a prompt, saying "Try again" but can't find out how to do it. Can someone help me create of function to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a proper `id` setup per image you can check if the data in the drop event is `turtle`.

See below.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if (data !== "turtle") {
    alert("Try again!");
    return;
  }
  var img = document.getElementById(data);
  ev.target.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  drop here
</div>

<img id="turtle" src="turtle.ico" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" />
<img id="fish" src="fish.ico" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100" />
```